# Making sense out of the definition for "morphism of geometric spaces"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to read "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups" by Demezure and Gabriel and I'm already stuck on the following definition.  A geometric space is defined to be a pair $(X, \mathcal O_X)$, where $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal O_X$ is a sheaf of rings, such that for each $x \in X$, the stalk $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_x$.

> Definition (word for word): A morphism of geometric spaces $f: (X, \mathcal O_X) \rightarrow (Y, \mathcal O_Y)$ consists of a continuous map $f^e:X \rightarrow Y$ and a homomorphism of sheaves of rings $f^f$ of $\mathcal O_Y$ into the direct image $f(\mathcal O_X)$ of $\mathcal O_X$, such that for each $x \in X$, the homomorphism $f_x: \mathcal O_{Y, f(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal O_{X,x}$ induced by $f^f$ is local, i.e. satisfies $f_x(\mathfrak m_y) \subseteq \mathfrak m_x$.

What is meant by a "homomorphism of sheaves of rings?"  Is this a natural transformation between the sheaves? (they are contravariant functors)  What is a direct image?  How does $f^f$ induce a homomorphism between stalks?  Finally, what is $y$?

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard term is locally ringed space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space). Do you know what a sheaf is, and what a homomorphism of sheaves is? If not, it seems like you should learn this more basic material first.

Comment: I know what sheaf, ringed spaces etc. are, but I've never heard of a homomorphism of sheaves.

Comment: It's debatable whether you know what a sheaf is if you don't know what a homomorphism of sheaves is... anyway, yes, a homomorphism of sheaves is a natural transformation. If $f : X \to Y$ is a map of spaces, there is an induced adjunction $f^{\ast} \vdash f_{\ast}$ between their categories of sheaves; the left adjoint $f^{\ast} : \text{Sh}(Y) \to \text{Sh}(X)$ is called pullback or inverse image, and the right adjoint $f_{\ast} : \text{Sh}(X) \to \text{Sh}(Y)$ is called pushforward or direct image. All of this is part of what it means to know what a sheaf is; details are on e.g. Wikipedia.